# Thousand separator by dots in a FormControl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have been wondering how to display a value with a thousand separator without changing the value in react. I have tried react-number-format and a couple of other libraries. I want the value to show the dots but in the handleChange get the original value. Does this need some special function or is there maybe an easy solution to this.

So basically if I write "1234567" it changes to "1.234.567" as I write it and even if it's possible adds a suffix in the end " USD"

Here is my FormControl

```
<FormControl
     className={"QuestionInput"}
     type="text"
     name="salary"    
     value={salary.value}
     onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
```

That is handled by a parent component which calls a webService each time the state is changed.

```
   handleChange(event) {
       var state = this.state;
       state[event.target.name].value = event.target.value;
       this.setState(state);
   }
```

Comment: Just for the record, setting state the way the code does now is considered bad practice. Instead, prefer creating a new object based off of the old state, like this: `this.setState({ [event.target.name]: { value: event.target.value } })`

Comment: To address the question, [this library might be of interest,](https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js) which also happens to have React bindings. If you're not interested in picking up another dependency, you can take a look at how it works.

Comment: @kingdaro Thanks for the tip and yes this library was exactly what I was looking for!